# How to control siunitx prefixes' (e.g. milli) style?

Tags: formatting, siunitx

It is not hard to generate units in `siunitx` in which the `milli` prefix will be ambiguously rendered as `m` and confused with `meter`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\SI{10}{\milli\tesla\meter}
\end{document}
```

Renders as `mTm`.

I would like to render the `m` for milli slightly different than the `m` for meter. Perhaps as sans-serif or a slightly smaller size.

How can I control the *style* of the prefixes in `siunitx`?

The only option I found involving prefixes is `prefixes-as-symbols` but it is something different.

Comment: I don't know if there's a separate font for prefixes, but you could do `\DeclareSIPrefix\milli{\textsf{m}}{-3}`...

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik, very clever, I didn't know one could override the existing prefixes. Anyway, a global option would be nicer.

Comment: There is no built-in support here as the entire unit should be in the same font. Moreover, the situation should _not_ be ambiguous: the standard output is `\mathrm{mT}\,\mathrm{m}`, note the space between units.

Comment: additionally, the unit order is such that 'm' (for meter) comes in the end in order to avoid precisely that confusion. So 'mT' would always be read as milli tesla whereas 'Tm' is tesla meters.

Comment: @JosephWright is this true also if one uses tight-spacing=true?

Comment: @alfC Tight spacing makes no difference: that's for things like `\times`.